# Can Grub error messages be hidden, as Ubuntu continues to load regardless?

Tags: grub2

can Grub 'error' messages that appear over the blue splash-screen be made to be hidden, as Grub continues through to load Ubuntu without any problems, and there are no effects within the desktop environment?

Grubs version is 1.99 rc1.

regards
Livio

Comment: Are you still looking for help with this or have you solved the problem? If you did find a solution please consider posting it here, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You would need to edit the file `/etc/default/grub`.

In this file you'll find an entry called `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`.  This entry must be edited to control the display of the splash screen.

The presence of the word `splash` in this entry enables the splash screen, with condensed text output.  Adding `quiet` as well, results in just the splash screen; which is the default for the desktop edition since 10.04.  In order to enable the "normal" text start up, you would remove both of these.

So, the default for the desktop, (i.e. splash screen only):

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

For the traditional, text display:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=
```

After editing the file, you need to run `update-grub`.

```
sudo update-grub
```

For more details, see this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

Comment: This doesn't hide *grub* error messages